# Interface decouples the client

Tags: c#

Can you please explain how interface decouples client.

Answer (score 4):

[Loose coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling)

Comment: and maybe also have a look at Polymorphism - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming#C.23

Comment: I prefer the Dependency Inversion Principle - http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/dip.pdf